# Add weeks to a date in twig format

Tags: date, twig

I'm working with twig and have the date and format working properly. `{{ yourDate|date_modify("+8 weeks")|date("m/d/Y") }}` yet when I pull in the twig fields I can no longer get it to work - any ideas?

```
{{ post.litter_born|date_modify("+{{ post.litter_ready.value }}") |date( 'M j, Y' ) }}
```

I think I must have the syntax wrong in this area here: `("+{{ post.litter_ready.value }}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concat the string with `~`

```html
{{ post.litter_born|date_modify('+'~post.litter_ready.value) }}
```

Comment: I am currently pulling in a related ACF field into WP/Timber using twig as well doing the same thing and this time its throws me a date of 10/17/1970 
`{{ post.get_field('puppy_litter').litter_born|date_modify("+"~post.get_field('puppy_litter').litter_ready)|date("m/d/Y") }}` would you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: I'd verify the data seperatly first with a dump and see what the output is. Maybe the best thing u could do is create a seperate question for this, I'm not that familiar with ACF

Comment: ACF is the Woprdpress Plugin Advanced Custom Fields and here is the Timber doc I was referencing: https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook

Comment: This seems to work for me:  ` {% set whelp_date = post.meta('puppy_litter').litter_born | date("F j, Y") %}
  {% set date_ready = post.meta('puppy_litter').litter_ready %}

  {{ whelp_date|date_modify("+" ~ date_ready)|date("F j, Y") }}`